# How to extract these acoustic features from audio files

Tags: python, voice-recognition, pyaudioanalysis

I was making a voice gender detector, and when trying new samples I need to get the features below from the audio samples, and I wrote this code that doos that; but apparently `audioFeatureExtraction` in `pyAudioAnalysis` doesn't exist anymore, what can I do?

https://github.com/Valentjno/SpeechGenderRecognition/blob/master/functions/new_sample.py

The acoustic features:

- `meanfreq`: mean frequency (in kHz)
- `sd`: standard deviation of frequency median: median frequency (in kHz)
- `Q25`: first quantile (in kHz)
- `Q75`: third quantile (in kHz)
- `IQR`: interquantile range (in kHz)
- `skew`: skewness (see note in specprop description)
- `kurt`: kurtosis (see note in specprop description)
- `sp.ent`: spectral entropy
- `sfm`: spectral flatness
- `mode`: mode frequency
- `centroid`: frequency centroid (see specprop)
- `peakf`: peak frequency (frequency with highest energy)
- `meanfun`: average of fundamental frequency measured across acoustic signal
- `minfun`: minimum fundamental frequency measured across acoustic signal
- `maxfun`: maximum fundamental frequency measured across acoustic signal
- `meandom`: average of dominant frequency measured across acoustic signal
- `mindom`: minimum of dominant frequency measured across acoustic signal
- `maxdom`: maximum of dominant frequency measured across acoustic signal
- `dfrange`: range of dominant frequency measured across acoustic signal
- `modindx`: modulation index. Calculated as the accumulated absolute difference between adjacent measurements of fundamental frequencies divided by the frequency range